# Induced representation of sign

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $S_{n-1}$ be the subgroup of $S_n$ that fixes n.
Consider sgn to be the permutation sign representation of $S_{n-1}$ as a $\mathbb C$-representation.

> What is the decomposition of the induced representation of sgn to $S_n$?

I know by Frobenius reciprocity that $sgn_{S_n}$ appears once. My guess is that $standard_{S_n}$ appears once.

I have looked at another question on this site that does it for $S_3$ and $S_2$. How to do it in general?

Comment: For general $n$ you would need to use Frobenius reciprocity to compute the multiplicities of the induced representation of $\text{sgn}$ with each of the irreducible characters of $S_n$. Assuming that you're given a character table for $S_n$ then this is a straightforward algorithmic computation.

Comment: Do you know that the irreducible representations are indexed by partitions? The induced representation you are describing is (by the Pieri rule) a sum of two irreducibles, corresponding to the partitions $(1,\ldots,1)$ and $(2,1,\ldots,1)$. This is the sign representation, and the standard representation tensor the sign.